# xjc store downloaded schema files while generation

Tags: download, xsd, schema, xjc

I've used xjc to retrieve the schema from an url. Is there any way to tell xjc to save these schema-files in a directory? So there won't be the need to re-download it every time?

Comment: Use catalogs to rewrite absolute URLs into local ones.

Comment: That doesn't help me. Some of the URLs are not accessible so I can't download them on myself. But XJC succeeds in downloading them and can create a valid mapping. So it would be nice if it could store the downloaded files.

Comment: "URLs are not accessible" and "XJC succeeds in downloading them" is a direct contradiction. Schemas are either downloadable or not. If XJC can download them, so can you. XJC does not employ any black magic (at least in this case).

Comment: @lexicore Could you please expand your first comment to a full answer? How to use catalogs etc... I have trouble with http://www.loc.gov/mods/xml.xsd referenced from mods-3-6.xsd

Comment: @koppor Please check the [wiki documentation](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-Catalogs)